# How to extract the error from a stderr in nodejs childprocess

Tags: node.js, child-process, stderr

I have not been able to find an answer in google or other places, I hope you can guide me.

I have a `node.js` app that calls an executable `(.exe)` file that sometimes fails, My code is the following:

```
const converter = childProcess.spawn('converter.exe', [source, destination], options);
converter.stdout.on('data', (data) => {

});
converter.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`Child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
converter.stderr.on('data', (data) => {

});
```

Everything works well, but when I get an stderr I don't know how to get the message, I logged the data and I got this:
stderr:  [image]

I can get a string using .toString(), the string is the following:

```
stderr:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "converter.pyw", line 23, in <module>
    doc = word.Documents.Open(source_file)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2146822496, None, ('El archivo parece estar corrompido.', 'Microsoft Word', 'wdmain11.chm', 25272, None))
```

My doubt now is, is it possible to extract the error message only? In this case the error message is **El archivo parece estar corrompido.**

I even tried using JSON object to parse it but i've got no luck.

**Edit:**
As I control the generation of the `.exe` file I will try using some try except code blocks (yes it's python code), but I don't know If I will still get text like sterr: Traceback... I'll edit this question as soon as I get my results.

Comment: It'd be good if you could edit your question and change those images to actual text code.

Comment: I did it for the string part because the buffer is very big and I can't copy it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was expecting from the beginning there is no built in method to extract the errors I get from my exe file, the error is a string that could be worked out to get the error message but that could be complex.

I tried using try except block in my python code that later is compiled into the exe file, it looks something like:

```
try:

except:
    sys.stderr.write('Error')
```

Now, the output in my error handling function is:

```
Error
```

I guess the answer in the end is to control the output that comes out of the childprocess file.

Comment: I don't know about Windows but on Unixen (MacOS, Linux, BSD, Illumos, Linux on WSL etc.) you can also return an exit code. Successful exit code is always 0 and failure exit codes are non-zero but you can use any integer for failures to signal different kinds of errors. Of course, returning an exit code means you need to exit the process. This is useful for command line utilities but perhaps not useful if your process is a server

Comment: ... You know how in C/C++ you have `int main () {...` - meaning `main` returns an int value? On Unix (where C was invented) that return value is the exit code. So obviously since Windows support C/C++ you **can** return an exit code (I assume most languages also allow this) but I just don't know how Windows handle it or if it even pass it to you